# Error: Unknown argument: platform ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I installed Ionic with Angular and the Android platform, immediately afterwards I started the "Ionic Cordova Build Android" command but gives me this error:
Error: Unknown Argument: Platform
[Error] An Error Occurred While Running Subprocess NG.

Comment: "ionic cordova build android" should small letter

Comment: how to did you installed locally or globally?

Answer (score 30):

If you run this command: ng add @ionic/cordova-builders

Answer (score 6):

You may need to install the packages as explained on
https://ionicframework.com/blog/updates-to-ionic-angular-toolkit/

Add update the angular.json file as below. (ionic-cordova-build and ionic-cordova-serve sections)

```
     "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
        },
        "ci": {
          "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
        }
      }
    },
    "ionic-cordova-build": {
      "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "ionic-cordova-serve": {
      "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-serve",
      "options": {
        "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
        "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
          "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

},

Comment: I have the same issue; I tried to do the same thing. It didn't help, same error. What's the proper incantation to get `ng` to understand this? Or what should `packaage.json` have under `scripts/ionic:build`?

Comment: Apparently `ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:production` works. But how do I get it to run that when I run `ionic cordova build` (and not when I run `ionic build` for quick tests)?

Comment: This should be accepted answer, save many hours...

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command: ng add @ionic/cordova-builders it should add the required builders that are missing from the angular.json file generated by the Ionic CLI.
it worked for me.